# Keyboard Shortcuts Creating Event Methods in Visual c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i know there is a way to quickly create a an event handling method like onPaint onLoad etc. by typing a small amount of the method then using the tab key. but i am a lil rusty and cant remember how? can anyone shed some light? i am using Visual c# express 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for code snippets: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5cc9b(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the design mode, when selecting particular control, you would double-click to create a new event handler (stub) for specific event. Here is more: [Creating Event Handlers in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s.aspx)